# Django generate a summary view

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)


class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, null=True)
    impressions = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    clicks = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    spend = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

I am trying to create a view where it displays for each model1 the number of ads the logged in user has associated with it + counts of the impressions, clicks and spend.

A quick mockup would be like:

```
===================================================
=Model1 Name=Model2 Count=Total Impressions=TotalClicks=
=    First  =       10   =        1        =     1     =
=    Second =        6   =        100      =     20    =
========================================================
```

I've been toying with an idea of a dict with multiple values for each model1 key but I can't figure out how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went for a dict that stores a list of the calculated fields, as so:

```
data = {}
for m1 in Model1.objects.all():
    list = []
    model2s = m1.model2_set.filter(user=request.user)
    if model2s:
        list.append(calculated field)
        list.append(Another calculated field)    
        data[m1.name] = list
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work to get the dict you are referring to:

```
data = {}
for m1 in Model1.objects.all():
    data[m1.name] = Model2.objects.filter(model1=m1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me off onto the right track, I've posted what I ended up doing.